# URL mapping in node js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

```
    router.get("customer/:customerId", async (request, response) => {
        console.log("Fetch customer with a particular customer ID")
    }
    
    router.get("customer/regions", async (request, response) => {
        console.log("Fetch all customers from a region")
    }
```

But whenever I make any request the request is being served by the first api(the regions is getting considered as customerId) and not the second one.How can we have url mappings in these kind of scenarios?

Comment: Tried placing the `customer/regions` route first in order? I do not think Express can "know" that `regions` is not a valid `customerId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this problem three ways.

One is to switch the order of your two `router.get()`s. Express handles them in order. The way you have it, express thinks `regions` is a customerId.

Another is to append a regexp to your :customerId [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). For example, if your customerIds are 12-digit numbers you can do this to prevent that route from handling anything except `customer/123456654321`-style URLs.

```js
router.get("customer/:customerId(\d{12})", async (request, response) => {
  console.log("Fetch customer with a particular customer ID")
}
```

A third is to use the next() parameter. It tells express that your route handler refuses the URL, and to move on to try other matching routes.

```js
router.get("customer/:customerId(\d{12})", async (req, res, next) => {
  if (<<it's an invalid customerId>>) return next()
  console.log("Fetch customer with a particular customer ID")
}
```

You probably should use next() anyway to refuse invalid customerIds, and you should use random hard-to-guess customerId values. Because [Panera Bread](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2018/04/panerabread-com-leaks-millions-of-customer-records/).